# Enable line breaks in plain text fields

Tags: plaintext

When you create a Plain Text field it asks if you want to allow line breaks, but they are ignored when output in the template.

I don't want to have to use a rich text field just to enable editors to add a simple line break, but is that my only option?

Comment: Have you tried to use the https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html `|nl2br` function, maybe you need to escape it with `text = entry.yourTextField|nl2br` and after that `{{ text|raw}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use plain text, you just need to use a filter after

```
{{ entry.text | nl2br  }}
```

Comment: I thought it should be possible but a Google and stackexchange search found nothing.

Comment: Usually just `{{entry.text | nl2br }}` will work - no need for the `raw`

Comment: I have other stuff in there as well to fix the long term issue of nbsp being added in redactor fields, {{ entry.mapDetails | replace({'&nbsp;' : ' '}) | nl2br | raw }}, do I still need the raw?